# SortDirection always Ascending in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

This is my datagrid snippet:

```
<DataGrid Margin="0,4,0,0" Grid.Row="2" CanUserSortColumns="True" x:Name="grvDocs" Sorting="grvDocs_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Efile ID" Width="100" SortMemberPath="d.DocumentID">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DocumentID}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
```

This is C# code:

```
 private void grvDocs_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridColumn column = e.Column;

        ListSortDirection direction = (column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;
        //set the sort order on the column
        column.SortDirection = direction;
        e.Handled = true;

        BindDocuments(0, "LastStatusChangedDateTime", e.Column.SortDirection);

    }
```

Yet when I check `e.Column.SortDirection` it is always Ascending. Any idea how to solve this issue? I feel more like WTF rather than WPF.

Comment: I like your last sentence. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "do a e.ColumnSortDirection"?  `SortDirection` is a property, what are you *doing* to it?  The Sorting event lets you override the sorting behaviour--what are you doing to override this behaviour if you handling this event?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043040/how-to-change-first-sort-direction-on-wpf-datagridcolumn

Comment: yes but that problem looks different. My problem is no matter if I click the column 10 times, it always shows Ascending.

Comment: @PeterRicthie: *e.Column.SortDirection* is a porperty. e is instance of DataGridSortingEventArgs as shown in the code. Also please check out my edit. I get Ascending or null in SortDirection. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seams that the `SortMemberPath="d.DocumentID"` should be `SortMemberPath="DocumentID"`, due the binding is `Text="{Binding DocumentID}"`. Also you can use a `DataGridTextColumn` and set the `Binding` property if you only want showing text, just a tip. Hope helps...

Comment: This is not the problem. D.DocumentID is correct as I am passing this to my SQL which needs d in SQL query