# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn sorting issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, datagridtemplatecolumn

I know, lots of topics about that, but I couldn't find any resolution for my issue.

The ViewModel has a bool "UserNotification". The Column is showing a mail icon in the header if there is one or more rows with UserNotificatoin=true. Each row shows the same mail icon if the entry has a notification.

I'm using SortMemberPath="UserNotification" and tried all variations of SortDirection, but the behaviour is always the same:
When the user clicks once on the column header, the entries with UserNotification=true are sorted to the end, just the second click brings them on top. We need them on top with just one click.

For several reasons, we didn't use CollectionView but an ObservableCollection for the member "TradesView", and fill it with filtered entries (no sorting in the Collection itself). This should not be the problem, because the next column contains the Id (integer), and the sorting works perfectly fine (one click on the header brings the smallest number to the top).

Here is the xaml code:

```
<DataGrid Name="Blotter"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TradesView}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTrade, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                CanUserSortColumns="True"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                GridLinesVisibility="All"
                HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray">
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding EditTradeCommand}"/>
                <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteTradeCommand}"/>
                <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding RefreshTradesCommand}"/>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="UserNotification" SortDirection="Descending" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <Image Source="../Resources/Mail.ico" Width="16" Height="16"
                               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Blotter,
                                                    Path=DataContext.GlobalNotification, 
                                                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Blotter_OnMouseDoubleClick"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="../Resources/Mail.ico" Width="16" Height="16"
                                   Visibility="{Binding UserNotification, 
                                Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" SortMemberPath="TradeId" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding TradeId}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I tried a lot of options - I even changed UserNotification to an integer, because the Id column works. But it ended in the same behaviour. I also tried a normal CheckBoxColumn without success. So I don't know if it has to do with the implementation of the TemplateColumn itself. By the way - I already tried it without DataGridTemplateColumn.Header and DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle.

Comment: This is not addressing your question, but why are you controlling the visibility of the column header image? Wouldn't you always want the header image to show?

Comment: Nice comment. I asked the client the same, but he just wants to see this icon when there is at least one entry with notification. But in a way it makes sense - imagine a huge list, and somewhere in the invisible part there is a notification. So with the header, you can see if something appeared...

Comment: This answer might be what you are looking for: [Stack Overflow Article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985125/wpf-datagrid-default-sort-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. But it just leads to presorting when the collection changes which I don't want for this property. And this presorting also goes wrong, no matter if I put Ascending or Descending.

Comment: Refer this answer and see if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043040/how-to-change-first-sort-direction-on-wpf-datagridcolumn . Also you must be aware that i think templatecolumns don't resort when the underlying data changes...

Comment: Wow, this works! Thank you a lot, I didn't find this Question on my research.  But after configuring the SortDirection in xaml, I never thought it would need additional code behind to manage that. But I don't agree with your comment about TemplateColumns - I use them a lot and changing data is a basic case and I never had problems with that...

Comment: I added this to make sure this workaround just runs for my problem column: (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Column.SortMemberPath) &&
                e.Column.SortMemberPath.Equals("UserNotification")

Comment: @StefanR. Glad it helps you :)