# Why sorting DataGridView works only once

Tags: c#, datagridview

I load a file from my Form and then I create a TabControl with what I load from the file.

```
private void createTabControl()
{
  tabControl = new TabControl();
  tabControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  foreach (File file in loadedFiles)
  {
    List<String> animals = new List<String>();
    foreach (Animal animal in file.Animals.Values)
    {
      animals.Add(animal);
    }
    TabPage tabPage = new TabPage(Path.GetFileName(file));
    tabControl.TabPages.Add(tabPage);

    DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView():
    dataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.fill;

    dataGridView.DataSource = animals;
    dataGridView.ReadOnly = true;

    tabPage.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
    dataGridView.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += (sender, e) => DataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender, e, dataGridView);
  }
}
```

Now I need to sort Ascending or Descending by the Name of the animals.

```
private void DataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e, DataGridView dataGridView)
{
  if (dataGridView.DataSource is List<String> animals)
  {
    string columnName = dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
    if (columnName == "Name")
    {
      if (dataGridView.SortOrder == SortOrder.None || dataGridView.SortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
      {
        animals.sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
      }
      else
      {
        animals.sort((x, y) => string.Compare(y.Name, x.Name));
      }
    }
  }
  dataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

With that when I click on the header for the first time, the DataGridView sort all the data but when I click a second time, that do nothing.

What is wrong with what I have done ?

Comment: Use debugger to check if `SortOrder` actually changes whenever you clicked. Not familiar with DataGridView, but some threads suggest you sort [in different way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3861480/16606026).

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang Thanks but I tried sorting like the comment you suggest but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I simply used a variable.

```
// Add the variable sortDirection    
private string sortDirection = "descending";

private void DataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e, DataGridView dataGridView)
{
  if (dataGridView.DataSource is List<String> animals)
  {
    string columnName = dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
    if (columnName == "Name")
    {
      if (sortDirection == "descending")
      {
        // change the variable for next use
        sortDirection = "ascending";
        animals.sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
      }
      else
      {
        // change the variable for next use
        sortDirection = "descending";
        animals.sort((x, y) => string.Compare(y.Name, x.Name));
      }
    }
  }
  dataGridView.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: In addition to @JeremyCaney's comment, you won't get a lot of upvotes on answers that aren't detailed, easy to read, fun, relevant & educational. Your answer has none of these qualities: *So I simply used a variable.*